# raise the Android Files app in the Download folder and let the user manipulate files

Tags: android

I do not need to let the user pick a file and return its name to my app. I need to put a file in the Downloads folder, then raise the Files app, navigated to that folder, the same way as if the user had tapped on the Files icon. The user can then manipulate the file, such as by tapping on it to launch its default handler.

But the various `Intent` ways to do this give me a file picker, where tapping on the file does not raise its default handler. This is what we have so far:

```
public void openDownloadsFolder() {
    File downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

    Uri contentUri = getUriForFile(requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", downloadsDir);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "*/*");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setPackage("com.google.android.documentsui");
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Note that newbs should indeed not set the Package name, `"com.google.android.documentsui"`. We have a private app and we control the tablets, so we can set a package name if we need to.

---

Here's another attempt. This time we select the Samsung Files app and invoke the app launcher. And we can even successfully pass in the correct path to the Downloads folder. But there are still two bugs.

```
public void openFilesApp() {
    String filesAppPackageName = "com.google.android.documentsui";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(filesAppPackageName, "com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity");
    intent.setComponent(componentName);
    File downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    intent.putExtra("com.google.android.documentsui.folderPath", downloadsDir.getPath());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The first bug is that when the user taps on a file name, this still does not launch that file's handler. (We specifically want to tap an APK file and install it, but that's irrelevant to the question. If the user feels like tapping a TXT file, then we want to view it.)

The second bug is that if the user has already ran the Files app, and navigated it to another folder - such as Videos - then the intent launcher does not push the app back to the correct folder. It leaves it in the wrong folder.

---

Here's another attempt. This one DOES raise the interactive Files app, so the user can manipulate the files, but it does NOT navigate to the Downloads folder!

```
public void openFilesApp() {
    String filesAppPackageName = "com.sec.android.app.myfiles";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(filesAppPackageName, "com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.MainActivity");
    intent.setComponent(componentName);
    File downloadsDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    intent.putExtra("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.external.ui.folderPath", downloadsDir.getPath());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: That looks like very bad code. Anyhow you did not tell what your code does.

Comment: Where is this getUriForFile() from? And why would it be usable for a directory?